# Exponential integral over halfspace

Tags: integration, inequality, indefinite-integrals, exponential-distribution

I have the integral

$\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 e^{-w^Tx} dx$ that I want to integrate. The constraints are that $w^Tx = 1$ and $0\leq x \leq 1$ though I guess the latter is implied by the domain of integration anyway. $w, x$ are vectors. Is there a nice way to go about this problem?

Edit: Note that this is equivalent to integrating over the intersection of a simplex and a box if we take $t_i = w_ix_i$.

Thanks

Comment: Simply use $e^{x+y}=e^x\,e^y$.

Comment: @MarkViola How do I impose the linear inequality constraint though?

Comment: I've thought about doing the variable substitution $t_i = \sum_{j=1}^i w_ix_i$ but then I'm not sure what $dx_i/dt_i$ should be (and not sure that $1/w_i$ works as $t_i$ can definitely change without $x_i$ changing)

Comment: Oh wait -- I guess if I do the substitution $t_i = w_ix_i$, then this basically becomes $(1/\Pi_i w_i) e^{-1}$?

Comment: Actually that won't work for $w_i < 1$

Comment: Why won't it work for $w_i<1$?